# submit data by javascript Partially

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a javascipt and jquery function to submit data that read from an existed table:

```
<table class="table-style" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;" rowspan="2">Post Type</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">Show/Hide admin bar by the post status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Published</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Pending For Review</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Draft</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>post </td>
            <td align="center">
                <label class="toggle-switchy" data-size="sm">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="">
                    <span class="toggle">
                        <span class="switch"></span>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <label class="toggle-switchy" data-size="sm">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="">
                    <span class="toggle">
                        <span class="switch"></span>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <label class="toggle-switchy" data-size="sm">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="">
                    <span class="toggle">
                        <span class="switch"></span>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>page </td>
            <td align="center">
                <label class="toggle-switchy" data-size="sm">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="">
                    <span class="toggle">
                        <span class="switch"></span>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <label class="toggle-switchy" data-size="sm">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="">
                    <span class="toggle">
                        <span class="switch"></span>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="save_settings" class="button button-primary" onclick="readValuesAndStates()">Save Settings</button>
```

and here is the js function :

```
function readValuesAndStates() {

        // Create a form and append the values and states
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.method = "POST";

        var tableData = [];
        var list = document.getElementById("myListTable");
        var items = list.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var values = [];

        alert(items.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var value0 = items[i].getAttribute("value");
            if (value0 !== null) {
                values.push(value0);

                // Create a new hidden input for the post type (unique name)
                var input1 = document.createElement('input');
                input1.type = 'hidden';
                input1.name = 'value' + i;
                input1.value = value0;
                form.appendChild(input1);

            } 
        }

        alert(JSON.stringify(values));

        $("#myTable tr").slice(2).each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var rowData = {
                label: row.find("td:first").text().trim(),
                state1: row.find("td:eq(1) input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
                state2: row.find("td:eq(2) input[type='checkbox']").length ? (row.find("td:eq(2) input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0) : -1,
                state3: row.find("td:eq(3) input[type='checkbox']").length ? (row.find("td:eq(3) input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0) : -1,
            };

            var input2 = document.createElement('input');
            input2.type = 'hidden';
            input2.name = 'label';
            input2.value = rowData.label;
            form.appendChild(input2);

            var input3 = document.createElement('input');
            input3.type = 'hidden';
            input3.name = 'publish';
            input3.value = rowData.state1; 
            form.appendChild(input3);

            var input4 = document.createElement('input');
            input4.type = 'hidden';
            input4.name = 'pending';
            input4.value = rowData.state2; 
            form.appendChild(input4);

            var input5 = document.createElement('input');
            input5.type = 'hidden';
            input5.name = 'pending';
            input5.value = rowData.state3; 
            form.appendChild(input5);

            tableData.push(rowData);

        });

        alert(JSON.stringify(tableData));

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();

        return tableData;
    }
```

the function alert the corrected data but can't submit

here is the php code that read the POST data :

```
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    
            // Creating arrays to save POST data
        $values = $_POST['values'];
        $tableData = $_POST['tableData'];
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($values);
        print_r($tableData);
        echo "</pre>";
}
```

I try to print the $values only but it POST as the last item in the array only Note that I print_r($_POST); to ensure if the array was POST correctly or not.

and the array tableData couldn't be submitted at all .

I can't find the mistakes in my code.

help me please

Comment: what is value in `input2.value = value;` ?

Comment: sorry for the mistake I've edited the function

Answer (score 0):

You have to use array notation when using same input name.

Demo: https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/zmgxc?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=

```js
function readValuesAndStates() {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.method = "POST";
        var tableData = [];
        // here read data from a list called "myListTable" 
        var list = document.getElementById("myListTable");
        var items = list.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var values = [];
        //alert(items.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var value0 = items[i].getAttribute("value");
            if (value0 !== null) {
                values.push(value0);
                var input1 = document.createElement('input');
                input1.type = 'hidden';
                input1.name = 'value' + i;
                input1.value = value0;
                form.appendChild(input1);
            }
        }
        //alert(JSON.stringify(values));
        $("#myListTable tr").slice(2).each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var rowData = {
                label: row.find("td:first").text().trim(),
                state1: row.find("td:eq(1) input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
                state2: row.find("td:eq(2) input[type='checkbox']").length ? (row.find("td:eq(2) input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0) : -1,
                state3: row.find("td:eq(3) input[type='checkbox']").length ? (row.find("td:eq(3) input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0) : -1,
            };
            console.log(rowData)
var input2 = document.createElement('input');
            input2.type = 'hidden';
            input2.name = 'label[]';
            input2.value = rowData.label;
            form.appendChild(input2);

            var input3 = document.createElement('input');
            input3.type = 'hidden';
            input3.name = 'publish[]';
            input3.value = rowData.state1; 
            form.appendChild(input3);

            var input4 = document.createElement('input');
            input4.type = 'hidden';
            input4.name = 'state2[]';
            input4.value = rowData.state2; 
            form.appendChild(input4);

            var input5 = document.createElement('input');
            input5.type = 'hidden';
            input5.name = 'state3[]';
            input5.value = rowData.state3; 
            form.appendChild(input5);

            tableData.push(rowData);

        });
        console.log(tableData);
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
        return;// data;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-style" id="myListTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;" rowspan="2">Post Type</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;" colspan="3">Show/Hide admin bar by the post status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Published</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Pending For Review</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Draft</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>post </td>
            <td align="center">
                <label class="toggle-switchy" data-size="sm">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="">
                    <span class="toggle">
                        <span class="switch"></span>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <label class="toggle-switchy" data-size="sm">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="">
                    <span class="toggle">
                        <span class="switch"></span>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <label class="toggle-switchy" data-size="sm">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="">
                    <span class="toggle">
                        <span class="switch"></span>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>page </td>
            <td align="center">
                <label class="toggle-switchy" data-size="sm">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="">
                    <span class="toggle">
                        <span class="switch"></span>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <label class="toggle-switchy" data-size="sm">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="">
                    <span class="toggle">
                        <span class="switch"></span>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="save_settings" class="button button-primary" onclick="readValuesAndStates()">Save Settings</button>
```

Comment: basically the function alerts everything well but can't submit the data correctly

Comment: what you are getting in `print_r($_POST);
`?

Comment: only one item from the list that its id = post_id : =>
Array
(
    [post_id] => 37
)

Comment: I've commented all form.appendChild() and then sun the code it still prin tone item from the list array although the form must be empty !!!!

Comment: I can see all the data 

<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     echo json_encode($_POST);
    
}
?>

Comment: https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/zmgxc?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=

Comment: also list array with one item {"post_id":"40"}